# Sed not finding and replacing

Tags: sed

I have a file that I am translating to Chinese and some of the strings are not being detected. I'm guessing it has something to do with the '1'

Here's and example of something that my sed statement isnt catching

```
 sed -i  's|('1' = enabled)|（'1'=启用）|' TranslatedDiag.txt
```

How should I encapsulate this?

Comment: Use double quotes : `sed -i "s|('1' = enabled)|（'1'=启用）|"`.

Comment: considered as typo (quotes issue)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below

sed -i  's|enabled|启用|' TranslatedDiag.txt

Regards
Ratnesh Kumar Gupta